# How to pass a changing value through lambda in a "KeyRelease" function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to change the score label every time the user types in the correct answer but when I type in the correct answer the score increases to 10 but the expected **new** answer of the next equation generated won't change and stays at the initial value it started at because the "check" function receives the "ans" variable which is assigned before.

How can I fix that problem?

```py
def check(ans, text:tkinter.Text,score,current_stage,q_num,eq, event=None):
    
    ans = calc(eq)

    print(f"real answear = {ans}")
    temp = str(text.get("0.0", "end").strip())
    print(f"my answear = {temp}")

    if str(text.get("0.0", "end").strip()) == str(ans):
         is_correct = True       
    else:
         is_correct = False

    if is_correct:
        ans = calc(eq)
        score += 10
        q_num += 1
        inputtxt.delete(1.0,END)

        eq = generate_equation(stage=current_stage)
        ans = calc(eq)
        score_label_new    = tkinter.Label(master=master, text=f"Score: {score}").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
        question_label_new = tkinter.Label(master=master, text=f"{q_num}: {eq}").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        stage_label_new    = tkinter.Label(master = master,text=f"Stage: {current_stage}").grid(row=0, column= 3,sticky=W)

        if score % 100 == 0:
            current_stage += 1

    else:
        inputtxt.grid()
    

master = tkinter.Tk()
master.title("Math")
master.geometry('400x400')

eq  = generate_equation(stage=current_stage)
ans = calc(eq)

score_label    = tkinter.Label(master=master, text=f"score: {score}").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
question_label = tkinter.Label(master=master, text=f"{q_num}: {eq}").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
stage_label    = tkinter.Label(master = master,text=f"Stage: {current_stage}").grid(row=0, column= 3,sticky=W)

inputtxt = tkinter.Text(master=master, height=5, width=20)

inputtxt.bind("<KeyRelease>", 
lambda
 ans=ans,
 text=inputtxt,
 score = score,
 current_stage = current_stage,
 q_num=q_num,
 eq = eq: 
 #linked ==>
check(ans, text,score,current_stage,q_num,eq))


inputtxt.grid()

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you're changing globals, you need to add `global eq` and `global ans` at the start of the function.  You can delete the first two `ans = calc(eq)` in that case, although it's not clear you really need `ans` as a global.  You can easily generate it when you need it, which is only once.

Comment: I think that it being global won't change the fact it can't be updated inside the function which is being constantly called

Comment: @Guyzvi kinda confusing what you want to do, anyways, no point of passing something as an argument to a function if you immediately redefine it to something completely else. use of `global` is meant for changing what the variable refers to from outside the global scope (like in a function)

Comment: The global issue is EXACTLY the problem.  It's not being "constantly called".  It's being called when a key is released, and you only change the value when the answer is correct.  You shouldn't be passing those in the lambda if you need to change the value globally, which you do.

Comment: Thanks, it actually works! I finally understood the whole global thing I was not sure about

Answer (score 3):

This does what you want.  You do NOT want to capture any of those globals in your lambda; you always want to refer to the globals themselves.  It might be better to store your state info in a state class of some kind, so that you aren't literally using globals, but this works.  Note that I had to fake your `calc` and `generate_equation` functions, since you didn't give us a complete, runnable example:

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import W,END
import random

def calc(eq):
    return int(eq)

def generate_equation(stage=0):
    return str(random.randint(0,100))

current_stage = 1
score = 0
q_num = 1

def check(text:tkinter.Text, event=None):
    global eq 
    global score
    global q_num
    global current_stage
    ans = calc(eq)

    print(f"real answear = {ans}")
    temp = str(text.get("0.0", "end").strip())
    print(f"my answear = {temp}")

    if str(text.get("0.0", "end").strip()) == str(ans):
         is_correct = True       
    else:
         is_correct = False

    if is_correct:
        score += 10
        q_num += 1
        inputtxt.delete(1.0,END)

        eq = generate_equation(stage=current_stage)
        score_label_new    = tkinter.Label(master=master, text=f"Score: {score}").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
        question_label_new = tkinter.Label(master=master, text=f"{q_num}: {eq}").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        stage_label_new    = tkinter.Label(master = master,text=f"Stage: {current_stage}").grid(row=0, column= 3,sticky=W)

        if score % 100 == 0:
            current_stage += 1

    else:
        inputtxt.grid()
    

master = tkinter.Tk()
master.title("Math")
master.geometry('400x400')

eq  = generate_equation(stage=current_stage)
ans = calc(eq)

score_label    = tkinter.Label(master=master, text=f"score: {score}").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
question_label = tkinter.Label(master=master, text=f"{q_num}: {eq}").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
stage_label    = tkinter.Label(master = master,text=f"Stage: {current_stage}").grid(row=0, column= 3,sticky=W)

inputtxt = tkinter.Text(master=master, height=5, width=20)

inputtxt.bind("<KeyRelease>", lambda ev: check(inputtxt,ev))

inputtxt.grid()

master.mainloop()
```

Here's a version that uses a simple class.  I also changed it to update the text in your three labels instead of creating new controls each time.

```
import tkinter 
from tkinter import W,END
import random

def calc(eq):
    return int(eq)

def generate_equation(stage=0):
    return str(random.randint(0,100))

class State:
    current_stage = 1
    score = 0
    q_num = 1
    eq  = generate_equation(stage=current_stage)

    def check(self, text:tkinter.Text, event=None):
        ans = calc(self.eq)

        print(f"real answer = {ans}")
        temp = text.get("0.0", "end").strip()
        print(f"my answer = {temp}")

        is_correct = text.get("0.0", "end").strip() == str(ans)

        if is_correct:
            self.score += 10
            self.q_num += 1
            inputtxt.delete(1.0,END)

            self.eq = generate_equation(stage=self.current_stage)
            score_label.configure(text=f"Score: {state.score}")
            question_label.configure(text=f"{state.q_num}: {state.eq}")
            stage_label.configure(text=f"Stage: {state.current_stage}")

            if self.score % 100 == 0:
                self.current_stage += 1

        else:
            inputtxt.grid()

state = State()

master = tkinter.Tk()
master.title("Math")
master.geometry('400x400')

score_label    = tkinter.Label(master=master, text=f"score: {state.score}")
score_label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
question_label = tkinter.Label(master=master, text=f"{state.q_num}: {state.eq}")
question_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
stage_label    = tkinter.Label(master = master,text=f"Stage: {state.current_stage}")
stage_label.grid(row=0, column= 3,sticky=W)

inputtxt = tkinter.Text(master=master, height=5, width=20)

inputtxt.bind("<KeyRelease>", lambda ev: state.check(inputtxt,ev))

inputtxt.grid()

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Extra lines don't cost more money.  In my opinion, it reads better to have them on separate lines.  It's exactly the reason we don't write `import os, sys, datetime`.

Comment: I can get behind the idea of not using this with imports, but since PEP 8 doesn't specify the same about `global` as far as I know, I guess that it is quite opinionated, but I agree that readability is somewhat better with this approach

Comment: Please note that `self.score += 10` does not update the *class variable `score`*, but create an *instance variable* `score` instead.  You can verify that by printing the values of `state.score` (instance variable) and `State.score` (class variable) after executing `state.check(...)`.

Comment: I'm not worried about the class variable.  I created a singleton instance of the class, and everything is working through that instance.